# Text on a glass form not appearing right

Tags: winforms, aero, aero-glass

On a `WinForm` with an extended borders, when i place a text on the glass area it doesn't appear right.

This is how the text looks like `Status`

[a busy cat http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/4732/95454282.png](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/4732/95454282.png)
![form][1]

how can i fix the text to appear normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text in Winforms is rendered with an alpha of 0.  Which makes it *transparent* when you draw on glass.  So you'll see the background color, not the ForeColor you selected.

Drawing text on glass is troublesome, you can't get it easily anti-aliased correctly since the background of the text isn't well defined.  Note how the screenshot shows how Windows addresses that problem, the text in the window caption has a milky-white background, thus ensuring that the anti-aliasing properly blends the letter into the background.

Which is what you need to do as well.  You get text drawn like that with pinvoke, DrawThemeTextEx() with the DTT_GLOWSIZE flag option.  Visit pinvoke.net for the required declarations or use [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15394/Drawing-smooth-text-and-pictures-on-the-extended-g).  And don't forget to provide a fallback so this window still looks decent on older Windows versions.  And newer versions, glass is no longer appropriate for Windows 8.

Comment: Drawing the text works, but it's hard to draw every single text in the form, but thanks anyway. And yes i have a different methods for each windows version.

Comment: Why would text be rendered with an alpha of 0?  Or is it some legacy rendering that renders with no alpha, and just defaults to zero?